# How can I make the css code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

With this CSS I make the animation of the three Divs, said animation consists of putting the second div on top of the first, passing the first one back and moving the third div to the second position and thus showing all the divs one by one.

```css
html, body { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; }
.card{
  position: absolute;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  animation-name: cards-animation;
  animation-iteration-count:infinite;
  animation-duration: 6s;
}
.card-blue{
  background-color:blue;
  animation-delay: 1s;
} 
.card-red{
  background-color:red;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
.card-green{
  background-color:green;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

@keyframes cards-animation {
  0%  {
    transform: scale(0.75) ;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  9% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateY(40px);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  33% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateY(40px);
    z-index: 2;
  }
  42% {
    transform: translateY(80px);
    z-index: 3;
  } 
  66% {
    transform: translateY(80px);
    z-index: 3;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    transform: translateY(130px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(0.75) translateY(40px);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  } 
  90% {
    transform: scale(0.75);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="card card-blue"></div>
<div class="card card-red"></div>
<div class="card card-green"></div>
```

What I need is to know how I can pass the CSS code that makes that animation to a Javascript code, I mean to have the same animation but instead of doing it with CSS, do it with Javascript in order to have more control over it.

```
<div class="card card-blue"></div>
<div class="card card-red"></div>
<div class="card card-green"></div>
```

Comment: People will disapprove of this question in its current form - you should include specifically *what you want to achieve by using javascript*. That way we'll understand if you really need a js solution, or if your css can be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript can theoretically do anything that css can do - it's just a lot (*a lot*) more work in most cases. For animations, the tool you need is `window.requestAnimationFrame(callback)` - this allows you to queue an animation task for the next rendering frame. By recursively calling `window.requestAnimationFrame` you can perform updates on every frame, and by using `performance.now()` to measure the time you can perform updates based on real time.

For example, let's animate the `left` property with `window.requestAnimationFrame`, `performance.now`, and `Math.sin`:

```js
let applyLeftSinAnimation = (item, hz, px) => {
  
  // `hz` controls oscillations per second
  // `px` controls oscillation magnitude in pixels

  // Returning `result` from this function provides a way to stop the
  // animation:
  // let controlAnim = applyLeftSinAnimation(someElem);
  // controlAnim.stop(); // Stops the animation
  let result = {
    active: true,
    stop: () => result.active = false
  };
  
  // Get initial time
  let ms = performance.now();
  
  // We can compile a number of factors into a single coefficient
  let sinMult = Math.PI * 2 * hz * (1/1000);
  
  // Add an async animation loop to the event loop
  (async () => {
    
    while (result.active) {
      
      // Wait for the next animation frame to be ready
      await new Promise(r => window.requestAnimationFrame(r));
      
      // Get millisecond delta
      let dms = performance.now() - ms;
      
      // Apply custom animation based on millisecond delta
      item.style.left = (px * Math.sin(dms * sinMult)).toFixed(2) + 'px';
      
    }
    
  })();
  
  return result;
  
};

applyLeftSinAnimation(document.querySelector('.item'), 1, 100);
```

```css
html, body { position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; }
.item {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 50%; margin-left: 50%; margin-top: -25px;
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
        var countItem = 1;
        var totalSecond = 0;
        myFunction();
        function myFunction() {
            for (var i = 0; i < countItem; i++) {

                var transY = parseFloat(elems[i].getAttribute("transy"));
                var margin = parseFloat(elems[i].getAttribute("margin"));
                var get = elems[i].getAttribute("get");
                if (get === "n") {
                    transY = transY + 1;
                    margin = margin + 1;

                    if (transY >= 100 && transY < 130)
                        zindex = "1";
                    else if (transY >= 130 && transY < 160)
                        zindex = "2";
                    else if (transY >= 160 && transY <= 190)
                        zindex = "3";
                }
                else {
                    transY = 100;
                    margin = margin - 2;

                    if (margin < 0) {
                        if (get === "n") {
                            elems[i].setAttribute("get", "r");
                        }
                        else {
                            elems[i].setAttribute("get", "n");
                        }
                    }
                    zindex = "0";
                }

                elems[i].style.width = (transY) + 'px';
                elems[i].style.height = (transY) + 'px';
                elems[i].style.opacity = 1;
                elems[i].style.zIndex = zindex;
                elems[i].style.marginTop = margin + 'px';
                elems[i].style.marginLeft = (transY * .5) + 'px';
                if (transY >= 190) {
                    if (get === "n") {
                        elems[i].setAttribute("get", "r");
                    }
                    else {
                        elems[i].setAttribute("get", "n");
                    }
                }


                elems[i].setAttribute("transy", transY);
                elems[i].setAttribute("margin", margin);




            }
            totalSecond = totalSecond + 20;
            if (totalSecond > 1000) {
                if (countItem < elems.length) {
                    countItem = countItem + 1;
                }
                totalSecond = 0;
                myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, 150);
            }
            else
                myVar = setTimeout(myFunction, 20);
        }
```

```css
        .item {
            position: absolute;
            top: 20%;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
            background: white;
            opacity: 1;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div style="height:700px;width:300px;background:black;position:relative;margin:auto;">
    <div class="item" transy="100" get="n" margin="0" style="background:blue;opacity:0;"></div>
    <div class="item" transy="100" get="n" margin="0" style="background:green;opacity:0;"></div>

    <div class="item" transy="100" get="n" margin="0" style="background:red;opacity:0;"></div>

</div>
```